# What are the Japanese words for MMA terminology?

Tags: words, sports

Bit of a niche question specific (mostly) to words. I'm currently living in Japan and I'm a fan of mixed martial arts (MMA / UFC), watching and training. There are a couple of Japanese people I live with that have similar interests and as I find it hard to find common ground to chat this would be the perfect subject, though I can't seem to find any of the terminology to use in Japanese. All I've found is a list of Karate terminology which talking to my friend here nearly all exclusive to Karate and not MMA.

Does anyone know of any resources or can share with me words for common fighting terminology? For things like foot-work, block, jab, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are examples about them.

総合格闘技(MMA), パンチ(punch), けり(kick), 立ち技 and 打撃(punch and kick), 寝技(ground fighting), 関節技(locking technique), 落ちる(faint).

If you want to know about them more. This link help you. http://seesaawiki.jp/w/hakoyanagi/

Comment: This is a great resource, thank you! I was hoping many would be Katakana, I always feel rude if I guess a word to be taken from English so I can use those with confidence now. I'll pick those up in no time and be able to spend some time on the more complicated terminology.